# dynamical made dropdowns lists, how I use active class on each dropdown when chose any of the list

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, jstl

My JSTL tags code is below:

```
<ul class="megamenu skyblue">
 <!--1st level of categories  -->
 <c:forEach var="item1" items="${shoppingCart.categories}">
  <li id="headerCategory" class="grid" style="border-right: 1px solid #e5edec;">
   <a  class="inactive color1" href="#">${item1.name}</a>
   <div class="megapanel">
    <div class="row">
     <fmt:parseNumber var="i" type="number" value="${item1.id}" />
     <c:forEach var="item2" items="${shoppingCart.subcategories}">
      <c:if test="${item2.parentCategory.id==i}">
       <div class="col1">
        <div class="h_nav">
         <h4>
          <a href="#" onclick="dispProductCategoryWise('${item2.name}','${item2.id}')">${item2.name}</a>
         </h4>
         <ul>
          <fmt:parseNumber var="j" type="number" value="${item2.id}" />
          <c:forEach var="item3" items="${shoppingCart.subcategories}">
           <c:if test="${item3.parentCategory.id==j}">
            <li>
             <a href="#" >
              &#9830;${item3.name}
             </a>
            </li>
           </c:if>
          </c:forEach>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </c:if>
     </c:forEach>
     <%-- <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${item1.image}" alt=""/> --%>
    </div>
   </div></li>
 </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript code is below:-

```
$(document).on('click', '#headerCategory', function(){
    alert("hello");
    $('a.inactive').toggleClass('inactive active');
    //$(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
});
```

And css is :-

```
.skyblue li a.active{
    background:#EF5F21;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.skyblue li a.inactive{
    background:0;
    color: 0;
}
```

When i run above piece of code, all the dropdown menu is active.But i want how only selected-dropdown will be highlighted.

Help me for highlighted the select dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#headerCategory', function(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('inactive active');
});
```

If that doesn't work, you will have to register your event handler differently:

```
$('#headerCategory a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive active');
});
```

Comment: your first code is working for first select. when I select another one the previous one till highlighted. I want previous highlight should be remove

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks mmgross. In your first code i add $('a.active').toggleClass('active inactive'); ,but one problem is that inside list I have a dropdown list. I chose inside dropdown list the header dropdown should be highlighted. can you give me some advice.